# Why are Slices insides structs "passed by reference" when passed into functions in Go?

Tags: go, struct, slice, mutable

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    a := SomeType{myslice: []int{1, 2, 3}, decimal: 2.33}

    for _, i := range a.myslice {
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
    fmt.Println(a.decimal)

    addOne(a)

    for _, i := range a.myslice {
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
    fmt.Println(a.decimal)

}

type SomeType struct {
    myslice []int
    decimal float32
}

func addOne(s SomeType) {
    s.myslice[0]++
    s.decimal += 1.2
}
```

The output for the code above is:

1
2
3
2.33
2
2
3
2.33

Even though i have not passed the SomeType object a by reference the myslice field is being modified in the original object. Why is this happening? Is there anyway to pass the entire object by value without having to create a copy of the original object?

Answer (score 2):

The slice is not really being *passed* by reference; if you append to it in `addOne`, its length will not change. But a slice *contains* a reference (or pointer) to its backing array. So when you copy a slice, the new one shares the same backing array with the old one.

The fact that the slice is inside a struct doesn't make any difference. You would see the same thing if you changed `addOne` to just take a slice instead of the whole struct.

Comment: What would you recommend I do to avoid this? Do i have to manually make make a temporary slice of same length, copy the old one into this and reassign the myslice field to refer to this temporary slice? Isn't there any elegant way to handle this?

Comment: The real question is, "Why is the function modifying the contents of the slice?" But yes, if you are using a function like that, and you don't want it to modify the contents of the slice, you would need to make a deep copy of the struct, including the contents of the slice.

Comment: @AnkithD, you should understand this triplet of facts: 1) In Go, absolutely everything is passed by value, ever. 2) You may take an address of a value and pass it--instead of the original value. Still, the pointer is passed by value. 3) Three built-in types have *reference semantics:* maps, slices, channels. It means that the values of these types behave as "descriptors" (or "handles") of/on certain complicated hidden structures. The values of these types are passed by value like everything else but each copy *refers* to the same underlying structure.

Comment: @AnkithD, for slices, such a "hidden structure" is the backing array, and when you assign a slice value to a variable, two resulting values refer to the same underying array--hence sharing it. To understand why slices were designed this way, it's better to first learn about Go arrays. Unlike certain other languages (like, say, JS or C#), a slice is not "the data structure implementing an array", it is *a view window to an underlying array.* Yes, with `make()`, it's possible to create a slice with preallocated (and hence "anonymous") backing array...

Comment: @AnkithD, ...but it's also fine to take an existing array and "slice" it. This is very useful for writing certain kind of algorithms--like parsing data transferred by network protocols. Without slices, when you'd want to make parsing functions to only be concerned with certain parts of a buffer (array) containing data, you'd have to explicitly pass around a pointer to that buffer, an offset from its beginning and a length after that offset--both limiting the span of items to access. Slices combine these into nice self-contained packages.